# Using Python's Find() in a while loop to return the index of words in a string

Tags: python, string, loops, while-loop, find

A problem I'm working on involves using a while loop to iterate through a string, using the Find() function to return the index of a specific word in that string whenever it appears. For this example it's finding the name 'Weena' in a string variable containing the entirety of The Time Machine. I am being asked to specifically use while loops and the Find() function, though I've already solved the problem using an enumerator.

```
for count, word in enumerate(time_machine_text.split()):
    if 'Weena' in word:
        print(count)
```

I'm used to foreach loops because I relied on them a lot when I was learning C#, so every looping problem I see I just default to foreach loops. Any advice to meet the task's requirements of using a while loop and the Find() function would be much appreciated.

Comment: A `while` loop keeps running until the check at the start evaluates to `False` - what is `False` when your task completes? What does `find()` return when there is nothing left to find?

Comment: Not clear what the output objective is. Do you want to know the offset (index) of each and every occurrence of 'Weena' in *time_machine_text* or just the number of times it occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just intialize `count` variable separately and use while loop to iterate through `time_machine_text.split()`. For example:

```
count = 0
words = time_machine_text.split()
while count < len(words):
    word = words[count]
    if "weena" in word:
        print(count)
    count += 1
```

Edit: This is the version using find() function

```
count = 0
words = time_machine_text.split()
while count < len(words):
    word = words[count]
    if word.find("weena") != -1:
        print(count)
    count += 1
```

Comment: Requirement is to use *find()*

Comment: Ah sorry, i forgot about that. I thought i only had to use a for loop. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks, I managed to work out my own solution based on this!